# Can't understand what sample function is doing

Tags: r

I am looking at code given below:

```
### forward sampling
ForwardSimulation <- function(start_state,Rate_matrix,length_time){
## Size of state space
nSt <- nrow(Rate_matrix)  

## State space
StSp <- 1:nSt       

## Choose state at time=0 from initial distribution

## X holds states of path
X <- vector(mode="numeric")  

## beginning state is start_state
X[1]<- start_state    

## T holds times of path (Note: more sensible would be to find T from  some exponential distribution(maybe))
T <- vector(mode="numeric")  

## In the beginning time is 0
T[1] <- 0                    
T[2] <- 1

X[2] <- sample(StSp[-X[1]],1,prob=Rate_matrix[X[1],-X[1]])
print(X[2])
print(-X[2])
print(Rate_matrix)
print(Rate_matrix[X[2],-X[2]])

## Simulate states and waiting times similarly as above
## until time is larger than length_time
cnt <- 2 ## counter

while (T[cnt] < length_time) {
T[cnt+1] <- cnt
X[cnt+1] <- sample(StSp[-X[cnt]],1,prob=Rate_matrix[X[cnt],-X[cnt]])
cnt <- cnt+1
}

## Output state changes and corresponding times
Path <- list()
Path$length_time <- c(T[1:(cnt-1)],length_time)
Path$St <- c(X[1:(cnt-1)],X[cnt-1])
return(Path)
 }


###Setting up the matrix
r1 <- 1 # 1->2
r2 <- 0.75 # 2->3
r3 <- 0.5 # 3->1
r4 <- 0.5 # 3-> 2
Rate_matrix <- matrix(c(-r1, r1, 0, 0, -r2, r2, r3, r4, -(r3+r4)), nrow    = 3, byrow = TRUE)

path_forward <- ForwardSimulation(1,Rate_matrix,5)
plot(path_forward$length_time,path_forward$St,type = 's',ylab = 'State',xlab = 'Time')
```

The above mentioned code is simply making a path using CTMC given some matrix. 
Why I don't understand is that Rate_matrix[X[cnt],-X[cnt]] and StSp[-X[cnt]] is doing in the sample function. I mean what does "-X[cnt]" mean in these cases.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do the same as `-X[1]` does in

```
X[2] <- sample(StSp[-X[1]], 1, prob = Rate_matrix[X[1], -X[1]])
```

In case the question is about negative indices in general, note that

```
1:3
# [1] 1 2 3
(1:3)[-1]
# [1] 2 3
```

That is, we return the original object without certain elements. The same happens in your code, just with matrices. So, `X[cnt]` is the state at the previous time period. Then `StSp[-X[cnt]]` is the state space without this previous state, while `Rate_matrix[X[cnt], -X[cnt]]` is the `X[cnt]`-th row and all but `X[cnt]` elements of it. That is, `Rate_matrix[X[cnt], -X[cnt]]` contains rates of transitioning from `X[cnt]` to all the other states.